# Unable to Force Spanish Locale in Xcode Project with CocoaPods Despite Configuration Changes

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, locale

I am facing an issue with my Xcode project that includes CocoaPods. Originally, the project had both English and Spanish locales, but now I need to remove the English language entirely and keep only the Spanish localization. Here's what I did so far:

I removed the English localization from the Xcode project.
I set Spanish as the default language in both the Xcode project and the Pods (blue icon in project finder).
In the Info.plist file, I configured CFBundleDevelopmentRegion and Localizations to be Spanish.
Despite these changes, I am still encountering a problem. When the system language is set to English, my app continues to use the English locale instead of the desired Spanish locale.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and ensure that my app consistently uses the Spanish language and locale, irrespective of the system's language settings? I appreciate any insights or solutions that can help me achieve this behavior. Thank you!